# traefik - HTTP to HTTPS WWW Redirect

Tags: https, traefik

I could not find a question similar to this, there were others mentioning https redirects, but not about minimizing the redirects.

Been looking for a solution, and could not sort it out yet.

We use Docker > Traefik for WordPress and have www as the preferred version for WordPress. There are multiple WP instances. Domains are added dynamically.

However, with this config, I am receiving two redirects, from http to https to https www

```
http://example.com/
https://example.com/
https://www.example.com/
```

Is there any way to minimize the redirect?

ideally **a 301 redirect** from

```
http://example.com directly to https://www.example.com
```

**Traefik config file as follows**

```html
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[web]
address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]

[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
entryPoint = "https"

[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
compress = true
[entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "email@domain.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onDemand = false
OnHostRule = true


[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "traefik.example.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

Comment: Just an idea: Start 2 Container..
The Wordpress Container: hostrule www.yourdomain.com
https://hub.docker.com/r/chauffer/nginx-301-https/ with hostrule yourdomain.com and redirect to https://wwwyourdomain.com

Answer (score 10):

Try replacing your `[entryPoints.http.redirect]` entry with this:

```
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
#entryPoint = "https"
regex = "^http:\/\/(www\.)*(example\.com)(.*)"
replacement = "https://www.$2$3"
permanent = true
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mLHXkv/1)

It will not handle the `https://example.com/` entry so you need to add:

```
[entryPoints.https.redirect]
regex = "^https:\/\/(example\.com)(.*)"
replacement = "https://www.$1/$2"
permanent = true
```

If you have multiple frontedns, the regex can get hard to handle, so instead you can  consider having [a label on the container](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#security-headers), like this:

```
traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true
traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost=www.example.com
```

As of 1.7 there is new option `SSLForceHost` that would force even existing SSL connection to be redirected.

```
traefik.frontend.headers.SSLForceHost=true
```

Comment: The `SSLRedirect` label doesn't handle the case `https://example.com` => `https://www.example.com`. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: The same way I described it in the section before the labels part - by using `[entryPoints.https.redirect]`

Comment: That only works on the entryPoint though (i.e., for all frontends).  I was wondering how it could be done on a per-frontend basis.

Comment: As there aren't any ready to use labels that will do what you want, you either have to make custom configuration, or replace the template file that uses the existing labels. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48498453/global-configuration-of-security-in-traefik-for-docker/51348868#51348868) I have some more info how to do it properly.

Comment: I ended up just using a redirect via my webserver.

Comment: They are adding a [new option](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3194) in 1.7 for all providers `SSLForceHost` that you can use to force the redirect even for existing SSL connections.

Comment: In docker-compose you can use env variable in place of the domain to keep config D.R.Y. 

(I just had to add something as an excuse to say @Stoinov : thank you so much! Great answer)

Comment: Using the proposed substitution, you'll end up with one slash too many. See [101 with current substitution](https://regex101.com/r/mLHXkv/9). Instead, use `https://www.$2$3`: [101 with slash removed](https://regex101.com/r/mLHXkv/11).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I had to do.  The above answer was helpful, but traefik wouldn't start because you actually need a double \ to escape in the .toml.

Also you still need to make sure you have the normal entry points and ports there.
Here's my complete entryPoints section:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    regex = "^http:\\/\\/(www.)*(example\\.com)(.*)"
    replacement = "https://www.$2/$3"
    permanent = true
  [entryPoints.https.redirect]
    regex = "^https:\\/\\/(example.com)(.*)"
    replacement = "https://www.$1/$2"
    permanent = true
[entryPoints.https.tls]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work with docker provider behind AWS ELB.

traefik container

```
/usr/bin/docker run --rm \
  --name traefik \
  -p 5080:80 \
  -p 5443:443 \
  -v /etc/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  traefik
```

traefik.toml

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"

  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
```

docker labels

```
  -l traefik.enable=true \
  -l traefik.http.middlewares.redirect.redirectregex.regex="^http://(.*)" \
  -l traefik.http.middlewares.redirect.redirectregex.replacement="https://\$1" \
  -l traefik.http.routers.web-redirect.rule="Host(\`domain.com\`)" \
  -l traefik.http.routers.web-redirect.entrypoints="http" \
  -l traefik.http.routers.web-redirect.middlewares="redirect" \
  -l traefik.http.routers.web-secure.rule="Host(\`domain.com\`)" \
  -l traefik.http.routers.web-secure.entrypoints="https" \
```

ELB listeners

[image]

Comment: Seeing your answer, I think you are referring to Traefik 2.0. I think the OP asked his question while using a version of 1.7 or lower. 

Edit: He asked the question 2 years ago when 2.0 wasn't released. Perhaps, but I don't know, your answer can help feature requests. :)

Comment: They're also missing the `www` part of the question.