# Traefik global frontend rules for certain entry-points

Tags: traefik

I'd like to create some global rules for how when traffic is routed to the backends. For example, attaching certain HTTP request headers (e.g. like "X-Proxied-By").

I'd rather not need to define these rules for every single front-end. Ideally, I'd also like to add some headers based on the entry-point.

Is this possible? I couldn't locate it [in the docs](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no - there is no easy way to do it [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48498453/48639).

You either manually set it up on your provider for each entry, or you update the template file and keep it up to date with each upgrade.